# NAT for a domain name change

Tags: domain, nat

We have a customer on a .local domain with a local MSP.  We are preparing to migrate the customer to an Azure VM DC and a real domain name.  Someone told me that we could use NAT in the on-premise firewall to forward the .local to the real domain rather than changing the domain name on each PC.  Is this possible, and if so, is it a good idea?

Comment: Either you've misunderstood your "someone" or they don't understand what they're talking about. NAT has absolutely nothing to do with domain names. The sentence "use NAT to forward .local to real domain" is nonsense.

Comment: Agreed, it is possible the person may not have used the word "NAT" but "route"...but is that even possible?  I did not think so.

Comment: We can replace all words in the phrase, that would be another phrase, probably even it might have some useful meaning. Please, could you do that and ask meaningful question in the first place, instead of giving us puzzles asking which words could be change to which and what meaning that could have? For now, nobody can say "possible" or "not possible" because nobody will understand what problem exactly you want to solve. Rename MS AD domain is possible if you don't have Exchange, but that has nothing to do with routing/firewall/NAT. Use NAT/route/firewall to forward domain name? What?